# How can I create an audio resource from a URL? (Trying to code a bot for discord.js v13)

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

I am trying to code a Discord bot to use search for a song on YouTube using `YTDL` and then play the song in a Discord voice channel.

I was able to play a song from a file saved on my PC so I know that it works and the volume is fine. Anytime I try to pass the Audio Player a YTDL result I get an error. And if I try the video URL directly, I don't get an error but nothing still plays.

Here is my code for the player:

```
const ytdl = require('ytdl-core-discord');
const ytSearch = require('yt-search');
const { createAudioPlayer, createAudioResource, joinVoiceChannel, AudioResource, StreamType } = require('@discordjs/voice');

module.exports = {

    name: 'play',
    description: 'joins and plays music',
    async execute(message, args) {

        const voiceChannel = message.member.voice.channel;

        //if command is empty
        if(!args.length) return message.channel.send('You need to provide a URL!');       

        //If user is in VC, join same channel
        if (voiceChannel) {
            const player = createAudioPlayer();
            const connection = joinVoiceChannel({
                        channelId: voiceChannel.id,
                        guildId: voiceChannel.guild.id,
                        adapterCreator: voiceChannel.guild.voiceAdapterCreator,
                    }).subscribe(player);

            //Search for vid and return first result
            const vidFind = async (query) =>{
                const vidRes = await ytSearch(query);
                return (vidRes.videos.length > 1) ? vidRes.videos[0]:null;
            }
            const video = await vidFind(args.join(''));

            //If there is a video result, save it as an audio resource and play it through audio player
            if(video){
               const stream = ytdl(video.url, {filter: "audioonly"})
                const resource = createAudioResource(stream);
                player.play(resource);
            }           
        } else {
            message.channel.send('You need to be in a VC first!');
            
        }
    }

}
```

And here is the error I get:

```
TypeError [ERR_INVALID_ARG_TYPE]: The "chunk" argument must be of type string or an instance of Buffer or Uint8Array. Received an instance of WebmDemuxer
    at new NodeError (node:internal/errors:371:5)
    at _write (node:internal/streams/writable:312:13)
    at Socket.Writable.write (node:internal/streams/writable:334:10)
    at Duplexify.ondata (node:internal/streams/readable:754:22)
    at Duplexify.emit (node:events:394:28)
    at addChunk (node:internal/streams/readable:315:12)
    at readableAddChunk (node:internal/streams/readable:289:9)
    at Duplexify.Readable.push (node:internal/streams/readable:228:10)
    at node:internal/streams/duplexify:180:13
    at runMicrotasks (<anonymous>) {
  code: 'ERR_INVALID_ARG_TYPE'
```

I have tried using the `creatReadStream` function but I found that only works on local files. I have tried looking at other Discord v13 bots and they don't seem to use the `createAudioResource` at all and instead create their own custom function to create an audio resource.

Any help at all would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can think of a few reasons you may be running into some of the issues you are.

First of all, just a disclaimer that I have never used ytdl-core-discord. I have only worked with ytdl-core, but the [npmjs page](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ytdl-core-discord) of the former states that the function call (I.e. `ytdl(video.url, {filter: "audioonly"})`) must be 'await'-ed. So try putting 'await' before that call and see what happens.

Secondly, you should check your intents. In order to stream audio you require the ***GUILD_VOICE_STATES*** intent. This may be the reason that using the URL directly does not do anything.

If neither of those options fix it I would recommend switching from library. From what I can see ytdl-core-discord is not updated to work with Discord.jsV13. A lot of things changed about audio in version 13 so I wouldn't be surprised if it no long works until being updated. You can go to the regular ytdl-core version which I have seen work with v13 or, as I would recommend, you can try play-dl. It does virtually the same thing, but it does not come with some of the problems and bugs that I have seen people and myself get with ytdl-core. Also, play-dl has great examples on its [npmjs page](https://www.npmjs.com/package/play-dl) that can help you along.

Comment: Thank you! I ended up switching to just regular ytdl-core and it worked fine. I had switched to ytdl-core-discord when I was troubleshooting a different error and forgot to change it back.